# Can I run a MarkLogic method which is specific to a role/access?

Tags: javascript, security, marklogic, roles

I need to run a couple of functions with a specific & custom role that I created which is similar to admin role. Is there any functionality in MarkLogic where I can call a function with a specifc role? Is there any examples for the same?

Answer (score 3):

This feature exists and is called an [AMP](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/execute#id_54880)  (temporary amplification of privileges)

1. Create a role with the extra execute priv, roles etc -but do not assign it to anyone
2. Create an AMP configuration - mapping  a specific function to the new role.  When the function is run, it will inherit the extra role.

Please note: For me, I always also make sure the the calling user is meant to have access to that function. This can be achieved with a en execute priv on the calling role and a security assert in the executed function.

Resources:

- [Privileges Documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/execute#:%7E:text=Amps%20temporarily%20amplify%20a%20user%27s,in%20the%20MarkLogic%20modules%20database.)
- AMP Documentation:

  - Source 1 -[Security Section](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/execute#id_54880)
  - Source 2 -[configuration info from Admin interface](https://api.marklogic.com/admin-help/amp)
  - Source 3 - You tag Javascript, so There is some [special information](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/functions#id_13020) since the amp is applied on the export.